# Applescript "Expected end of line but found property." error when using google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, alfred

I recently updated to OS Mavericks and it appears a few of my applescripts  dealing with Google Chrome have stopped working properly.

I have a simple function that opens chrome and creates a new window..

```
on openWindow()
  tell application "Google Chrome"
      activate
      set newWin to make new window
      tell active tab of newWin to set URL to "http://play.google.com/music"
  end tell
end openWindow
```

However, this gives me the error:
Expected end of line but found property.

referring to the "tab" in "tell active tab of newWin."
This [link](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2011/09/applescript-browser-tab-weirdness/) seems to offer a bit of help, but I'm still lost as to how to fix this issue. 
Can anyone help me get this working again? Thanks.

Comment: As regulus points out, your error is somewhere else in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem, also on OS X 10.9.4, where a very simple script

```
tell application "iTunes"
    return persistent ID of (first source where kind is library)
end tell
```

every now and then returns the exact same error message:

```
NSAppleScriptErrorBriefMessage = "Expected end of line but found property.";
NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "Expected end of line but found property.";
NSAppleScriptErrorNumber = "-2741";
NSAppleScriptErrorRange = "NSRange: {45, 2}";
```

<s>It's not a real solution, but in my experience a computer restart gets rid of the issue (for a while).
The whole problem looks like a bug in AppleScript to me.</s>

Turns out I was running a Windows VM using Parallels at the same time. In the VM, there was also an iTunes instance. In essence, I had two different versions of iTunes on the same system. One that understands AppleScript and one that doesn't. Addressing the OS X iTunes like this solved the issue:

```
tell application "/Applications/iTunes.app"
    return persistent ID of (first source where kind is library)
end tell
```

Perhaps the problem in the original question can be solved the same way.

Comment: Yup, problem was with Parallels, Uninstalling it and using VirtualBox instead fixed my issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with no errors in 10.9.2. So your error must be someplace else. I noticed I get your error if I call the handler using...

```
on openWindow()
```

However if I just use the following, which is how you should call the handler, then it works with no errors.

```
openWindow()
```

For example, run the code outside the handler like this and you shouldn't get any errors...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set newWin to make new window
    tell active tab of newWin to set URL to "http://play.google.com/music"
end tell
```

As such it leads me to believe you are not calling the handler properly.

Answer (score 0):

For that its simple

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
set newWin to make new window
tell active tab of newWin to set URL to "http://play.google.com/music" 
end tell
```

but for  that in full screen with no toolbar it is

```
    tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
set newWin to make new window
tell active tab of newWin to set URL to "http://play.google.com/music"
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "f" using {command down, shift down}
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem.
My issue wasn't with the script, it was somehow related to the version of Parallels I had installed on my device. Uninstalling Parallels fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

As hendrik said, if you specify that you want Chrome from Mac OS the issue should be solved. I was having this problem with Chrome, but then specified that I wanted to tell my Google Chrome on my mac os (Google Chrome.app) and it worked perfectly and compiled.

So based on the code above it would look something like this:

```
on openWindow()
    tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
    activate
  set newWin to make new window
    tell active tab of newWin to set URL to "http://play.google.com/music"
    end tell
end openWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it fixed without removing Parallels Desktop.

Here are the basic steps:

First, cancel App sharing from your Parallels Desktop VM

Second, you need reset the Launch Services with the following command:

> `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed -r -f -v -domain local -domain user -domain system`

Then, try your script again.